# Removed Sidebar in single product page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Hi Guys I have some problem regards removing the sidebar on my single product page,

I look for some php code to get rid of it but nothing works for me.

```
>     /**  * @snippet       Remove Sidebar @ Single Product Page  * @how-to        Watch tutorial @ https://businessbloomer.com/?p=19055 
> * @sourcecode    https://businessbloomer.com/?p=19572  * @author        Rodolfo Melogli  * @testedwith    WooCommerce 3.2.6  */   add_action(
> 'wp', 'bbloomer_remove_sidebar_product_pages' );   function
> bbloomer_remove_sidebar_product_pages() { if ( is_product() ) {
> remove_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar', 'woocommerce_get_sidebar', 10 );
> } }
```

inserting this code on my funtion.php but nothing happens
I used avada for my theme.

I manage to removed the sidebar but the products image and description stay on the right side of the page.

for more info please see image :
https://ibb.co/k9qtfxB

You can check the page here: http://sumuri2.us.tempcloudsite.com/product/customize-your-workstation/

I hope someone can help me with this thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
function remove_sidebar( $is_active_sidebar, $index ) {
if( ! is_product() ) {
return $is_active_sidebar;
}
return false;
}
add_filter( 'is_active_sidebar', 'remove_sidebar', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: thank you I will try this one

Comment: hi I used the code you gave to me this is the error while saving.

Your PHP code changes were rolled back due to an error on line 48 of file wp-content/themes/Avada-Child-Theme/functions.php. Please fix and try saving again.

syntax error, unexpected '”' (T_STRING)

line 48 is referring for this code: if( $index !== “sidebar-1” )

Comment: if you remove ( $index !== “sidebar-1” ) this line it will also work i have tested it
and please check  if you copied that code single quote and double quote is proper on your editor, i have edited  code add this code and check